# When to use transform.position and rigidbody.position in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, transform, game-physics

As the title says, I'm just confused when to use these positions and why.

Comment: There is actually difference between them but it depends on what you're doing. Why do you need to use them? What are you doing with them? That will help give you an answer

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I know all of these things dude :). Even I know what the difference between them. I'm just curious when we have a gameobject which has a Rigidbody component, does transform.position have any chance against rigidbody.psotion ? (As I know rigidbody is much faster than transform.position).

Answer (score 1):

If the object has a non-kinematic rigidbody, you shouldn't write to rigidbody.position, and setting should be done via Rigidbody.MovePosition  (or even better, addforce) - if you just write to rigidbody position you might break the physics simulation, i.e. you introduce dicontinuities and you risk you move being overwritten by next FixedUpdate too.

Comment: Ok, but when to use Transform.position?

Comment: use transform.position when you are not using rigid body (not using physics)